# Cross platform mobile app Editor

Tags: android, ios, windows, cordova

I am planning to develop a cross platform mobile app.
My app has to deal with camera, organizing pics.. I am planning to use PhoneGap for building the app. I need to select a user friendly IDE for developing my app. There are so many Editors in the market.

This is my first app and I am very confused which would be a best one to use. I am developing my app on Mac. I need a simple, user-friendly Editor. 
Can someone please suggest what pros and cons do I have using different Editors and a better one to use?

Comment: There are probably thousands of different editor comparisons out there, this questions holds little value by itself since it is very subjective matter. Anyways, my tip is Sublime, is it really good and has the possibility of many extensions. It is the one I used when doing crossplatform apps with JS (PhoneGap).

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using [Monaca](http://monaca.mobi/en/) for developing mobile apps using PhoneGap. It includes an IDE for developing by simply using web browser. The good thing is that you write your code just using HTML5 and Javascript and deploy it to the platform such iOS, Android and Windows 8.

There is a guide [here](http://docs.monaca.mobi/en/learning/quick_start/intermediate/) for create a simple app with camera using PhoneGap and JQuery mobile. It is very simple to do. You can have a try.

Answer (score 0):

For Cordova/PhoneGap development right on iOS devices we developed [GapCoder](http://gapcoder.com) IDE.